# how to pass array of objects in deeplink

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, deep-linking

I want to pass array in deeplink or in some url. How can i pass it?
This is what I've tried.

```
xcrun simctl openurl booted "some-scheme://<pageName>?value=[7,8]"
```

but now [] are getting encoded .
Also if i want to pass array of objects then how should it be passed?

Comment: You can encode objects in Base64 and then apply URL encoding before appending it to your URL. Before proceeding be sure to not have a design problem if you need to pass an array of objects on URLs

Comment: @MatPag Encoding and decoding is not possible. Wanted simple flow.